# What's the difference between setMethod("$<-") and set setReplaceMethod("$")?

Tags: r, r-s4

### Question

When programming in [r](/questions/tagged/r) with the [s4](/questions/tagged/s4) OOP system, **when one have to use `setReplaceMethod`?** I don't see what's the difference with the `setMethod` when adding `<-` to the name of the function. Does `setMethod("$<-")` and `setReplaceMethod("$")` are equal?

### Documentation

- I didn't find anything in the documentation with `?setReplaceMethod` or `??setReplaceMethod`. There is nothing except the usage.
- In StackOverflow, there is [several questions about setReplaceMethod](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BS4%5D%20setReplaceMethod) but none helping. I started to search a answer to this question when I saw it seem's is [not possible to use `roxygen2`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396768/how-to-properly-document-s4-and-methods-using-roxygen) to document methods created with `setReplaceMethod`
- I didn't find anything by [searching in r-project.org](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=site:r-project.org%20setReplaceMethod)

### Reproductible example

```
library(methods)

# Create a class
setClass("TestClass", slots = list("slot_one" = "character"))

# Test with setMethod -----------------------
setMethod(f = "$<-", signature = "TestClass",
  definition = function(x, name, value) {
    if (name == "slot_one") x@slot_one <- as.character(value)
    else stop("There is no slot called",name)
    return(x)
  }
)
# [1] "$<-"

test1 <- new("TestClass")
test1$slot_one <- 1
test1

# An object of class "TestClass"
# Slot "slot_one":
#   [1] "1"

# Use setReplaceMethod instead -----------------------
setReplaceMethod(f = "$", signature = "TestClass",
  definition = function(x, name, value) {
    if (name == "slot_one") x@slot_one <- as.character(value)
    else stop("There is no slot called",name)
    return(x)
  }
)

# An object of class "TestClass"
# Slot "slot_one":
#   [1] "1"
test2 <- new("TestClass")
test2$slot_one <- 1
test2
# [1] "$<-"

# See if identical
identical(test1, test2)
# [1] TRUE
```

### Actual conclusion

`setReplaceMethod` seems only to permit to avoid the `<-` when creating a set method. Because `roxygen2` can't document methods produced with, it's better for the moment to use `setMethod`. Does I have right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's the definition of setReplaceMethod

```
> setReplaceMethod
function (f, ..., where = topenv(parent.frame())) 
setMethod(paste0(f, "<-"), ..., where = where)
<bytecode: 0x435e9d0>
<environment: namespace:methods>
```

It is pasting a "<-" on to the name, so is functionally equivalent to `setMethod("$<-")`. setReplaceMethod conveys more semantic meaning.